# Sort DataTable by Custom List Order

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to sort a `DataTable` based on a particular column and an existing sorted list.
This is what I came up with so far:

```
public DataTable SortByID(DataTable table, string columnName, List<int> ids)
{
    DataTable result = table.Clone();
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row[columnName]) == id)
            {
                result.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works, but I think that there might be some other solution that performs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Linq, you can join the `List<int> ids` to the `DataTable` and since your list is already ordered, the results will be in that order:

```
var query =
    from l in ids
    join t in table.AsEnumerable() on l equals t.Field<String>(columnName)
    select t;

var orderedTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Without a benchmark, do you think this (the join approach) performs better? I'm not going to quote you on that.

Comment: Your method is doing a double loop and this is doing a join: I am not sure how in memory joins are done so I cannot say. However, this is more readable and compact so I would only worry about performance if this piece of code is the bottleneck.